# How to begin a new equation

Tags: latex

I have used the code begin{equation} in one item which used in the code begin{enumerate}, how can I begin the number one code begin{equation} in the next item:
item 1:
1
2
...
100

item 2:
1
2
...
100
How can I recount the number in the item 2? Thanks.

I have try to put the begin equation new but it doesn't make sense, please give me a full detail code if you can

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?